# How to get ID of a custom field in apex

Tags: apex, force.com, custom-object, tooling-api

I have a requirement to get the ID of a custom field in apex .

When we navigate to Setup-->Create-->Object--> Click on Object --> Click on field .In field detail page url we can find field Id

```
https://orgaddress/00NG000000EyFpU
```

how that can be accomplished dynamically through Apex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just now  i solved it and posted the answer . Thanks for your help @Daniel Ballinger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it done with Remote Action method for ToolingAPI.

```
        id objid = '01IG0000002EHp5';//Id of the object
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setEndpoint( URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v28.0/tooling/query/?q=Select+id,DeveloperName+from+CustomField+where+TableEnumOrId=\''+objid+'\'');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);    
        req.setMethod('POST');
        string a = res.getBody(); 
        list<String> lst = new list<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile('"Id":"(\\w+)","DeveloperName":"(\\w+)"').matcher(a);
        while(m.find()) {
            lst.add(m.group(2)+':'+m.group(1)); 
        }
```

Finally it returns a list with Fieldname:FieldId like below,

```
(Field1:00NG000000DFGuwMAH,   Field2:00NG000000DFGvXMAX,   Field3:00NG000000DFGvYMAX)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tooling Api for this. 
Code Sample

```
// Constructs the Tooling API wrapper (default constructor uses user session Id)
ToolingAPI toolingAPI = new ToolingAPI();

// Query CustomObject object by DeveloperName (note no __c suffix required)
List<ToolingAPI.CustomObject> customObjects = (List<ToolingAPI.CustomObject>)
     toolingAPI.query('Select Id, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix From CustomObject Where DeveloperName = \'Test\'').records;

// Query CustomField object by TableEnumOrId (use CustomObject Id not name for Custom Objects)
ToolingAPI.CustomObject customObject = customObjects[0];
Id customObjectId = customObject.Id;
List<ToolingAPI.CustomField> customFields = (List<ToolingAPI.CustomField>)
     toolingAPI.query('Select Id, DeveloperName, NamespacePrefix, TableEnumOrId From CustomField Where TableEnumOrId = \'' + customObjectId + '\'').records;

// Dump field names (reapply the __c suffix) and their Id's
System.debug(customObject.DeveloperName + '__c : ' + customObject.Id);
for(ToolingAPI.CustomField customField : customFields)
     System.debug(
          customObject.DeveloperName + '__c.' +
          customField.DeveloperName + '__c : ' +
          customField.Id);
```

For more information you can read [Blog Post](http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/). you can find tooling API wrapper [here](https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi) or if you want to do it manually then you can read the [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Tooling_API). But query will remain same for it.

Comment: Already i tried this Tooling API . when i execute the above code "invalid Object name CustomObject " error is coming .Whether this code works for you?

Comment: 'SELECT ID,DeveloperName From CustomField Where DeveloperName = \'FieldName(Without __c)\''; can you share your code it will help to identify or take help from doc . they are so easy to understand.

Comment: where i need to place this code.I am trying to execute the simply in Execute Anonymous ,'ToolingAPI toolingAPI = new ToolingAPI();'  but the error Invalid type: ToolingAPI.Sorry i am newbie:) Kndly help me out

Comment: you need to install wrapper class package from given link. then try to run this code Execute Anonymous