# How can we get custom field Ids in apex from a different user

Tags: apex, metadata

We need to get some custom field ids thru apex - we used to do it by invoking tooling api request, but now this requires the user has to have the permission "View Setup and Configuration" on his profile and we don't want users to get that access.
How Can we get it by running the query from a different user?

Comment: Check the accepted answer. It seems it is using tooling API via Standard Rest Service. you can give it a try.

Comment: what do you mean the accepted answer?

Comment: My bad. I was trying to mention about this link https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94991/how-to-get-id-of-a-custom-field-in-apex

Comment: I did it as well, but then the user needs the permission "view setup and configuration" on his profile for that and we dont want to grant it to him. Can we do that request based on a different user?

Answer (score 1):

> How Can we get it by running the query from a different user?

You can use a Named Credential to do this. [Set up the Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_define.htm&type=5) to use Named Principal authentication, assigning a user that has View Setup and Configuration permissions.

Then, [make your Tooling API callout against the Named Credential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm):

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();

req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setMethod('GET');
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query/?q=<your Tooling API query here>');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

Salesforce handles the authentication part for you and your unprivileged user doesn't have to elevate privileges to get the Tooling API results.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but got the response -"Moved Temporarily, StatusCode=302"
This is My method : 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        String metaDataQuery = 'Select+QualifiedApiName,DeveloperName,EntityDefinition.KeyPrefix,DurableId+from+FieldDefinition+Where+EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName=\'Account\'';
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint('callout:Admin_User/services/data/v45.0/tooling/query/?q='+metaDataQuery);
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);

Comment: The named credential : Admin_User - URL - my sf url
Authentication - Identity Type Named Principal, Authentication Protocol - Password Authentication
Callout Options - Generate Authorization Header is checked

Comment: @daveDev You'll probably want OAuth configuration on your Named Credential. Does your Endpoint URL have a path on it?

Comment: Nope - its only the domain. How can I configure OAuth?

Comment: I tried from the post  : https://medium.com/dyno-dev/calling-tooling-api-from-apex-1913933284da   and received response -  [{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]

Comment: @daveDev Apologies for my poor response time; I am traveling and can't "follow along" with the setup right now. Regardless, I think that the steps there *should* work. If you can't get the Named Credential working feel free to open a new question about that subject!

Comment: thanks -   I opened a new question - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258450/calling-tooling-api-from-apex-with-named-credentials-auth-connected-app