# Apex logic to find field utilization for an object?

Tags: apex

I am new to salesforce and I need to find out field utilization for an object through the apex. I need to find out all field of an object by its percentage of usage so that I can show it in LWC.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what actually you are doing and what you want to achieve

Comment: Have a look on [Field Footprint](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EShrRUAT) and [Find Where a Field is Used](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_references.htm&type=5)

Comment: I need to write code for it, I don't want to use any app like a field trip or any.. but I want similar functionality to be performed by apex code.

Comment: Are you looking for a percentage of how many records have values in a given custom field or are you looking for where your custom fields are referenced in other components? Pranay has answered the latter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Tooling Metadata dependency API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) to find where a particular object or field is used in your Salesforce system.

```
SELECT MetadataComponentName, MetadataComponentType
    FROM MetadataComponentDependency
    WHERE RefMetadataComponentId = '01I580000016giF'
```

Where `RefMetadataComponentId` will be the id of field or object, the Id that you get in URL when you open field description in SF UI.

The other easier way to find fieldId or ObjectId is to use tooling api as mentioned here,
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/95143/19118